# Using a comma instead of "and" when you have a subject with two verbs

Tags: conjunctions, commas

My question is exactly as mentioned in the title.

What do you call the sentence structure when a comma is used instead of "and" when you have a subject with two verbs (to describe two different actions) and when should such a structure not be used? See below. Hopefully what I mean will make more sense:

> ***"The fat hand descended onto the globe, stopped the spinning."***
>
> ***"Jessica turned away, looked out the window at the gathering darkness."***

Both sentences above are from a book.

Is the sentence below OK to you (it was written by me)?:

> ***"Theresa cast a glance at her phone as she got out of the station, pressed the start button."***

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Both your examples are from Frank Herbert's *Dune*, which is a very successful book from a very competent writer. But they're both ***stylized, literary*** usages that don't occur very often *anywhere*. Notice that in both cases, the immediately following text goes on to reference ***immediately following events*** within the narrative, whereas the two elements linked by a missing ***and*** are effectively ***simultaneous***. Imho that's at least *part* of the reason Herbert chose to discard ***and*** ("telescoping" those first two elements into "one preceding event", before the "next" event).

Comment: In case it's not obvious, my advice is that you accept Herbrert's usage as "valid" (don't kid yourself that he's not a competent writer). But don't copy it yourself - you'll probably *never* be in a situation where that's a good idea.

Comment: ...also, I haven't checked the first in detail, but the syntax of the second one would be beyond reproach if instead of ending with a full stop, it continued with ***and said***. But of course, Herbert knows perfectly well that it's poor writing style to litter your story with ***he said, she said*** if you can avoid it. Just leave it to the reader to silently *imagine* those unnecessary words identifying the speaker.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. It's very useful!

Answer (score 6):

When we have phrases joined together by words such as *and* or *but* , this is referred to as coordination. Words like *and* and *but* are called coordinators (or 'coordinating conjunctions'). Notice that when we have coordinations of more than two types of phrase or clause, we normally only put a coordinator before the last one:

- men, women **and** children
- red, white **and** blue

Each of the coordinated clauses or phrases is called a coordinate. Sometimes, we can leave out the coordinator altogether. This is called **asyndetic coordination**. It looks like this:

- They were all there: men, women, children.
- I love bananas, melons, pomegranates.

Notice there is no word *and* in the examples above. Asyndetic coordination normally happens when there are three or more coordinates. However, it is also, possible to use asyndetic coordination with only two coordinates, as in:

- She loves melons, pomegranates.

Asyndetic coordination is much rarer than normal coordination, and makes these sentences feel unusual and interesting. It is even rarer when there are only two coordinates. We wouldn't want to use sentences like these all the time.

When we have coordinations of clauses, we can often leave out information which would be repeated in the second clause:

- I ate the sandwiches, and Bob <s>ate</s> the cake.

Asyndetic coordination is quite common in these special types of "gapped" sentence:

- I ate the sandwiches, Bob the cake.

**The Original Posters examples**

The Original Poster's examples of asyndetic coordination are interesting and literary in feeling. They involve the coordination of two verb phrases without any coordinator. They are even more unusual than normal cases of asyndetic coordination, because they each have only two coordinates, not three.

Again, these are interesting and create an unusual atmosphere. But we wouldn't want to read a novel where every sentence was written like this. It would spoil the effect completely.

Comment: Asyndetic coordination also sometimes occurs in very informal speech: "He got up, had breakfast, went to the store. There he bought groceries..." I wouldn't advise learners to do this deliberately, though.

Comment: @alphabet Interesting! Why not?

Comment: You wouldn't sound too formal if you avoided it, but you might confuse your listeners if you overused it; it isn't generally a deliberate stylistic choice used for rhetorical effect.

Comment: I do wonder if anyone's come up with rules describing when us native speakers tend to do this. If so, such rules could certainly be taught.

Comment: I suspect that it's most common in coordinations of verb phrases. It also happens when a speaker suddenly decides to end a coordination after one of the coordinates.

Comment: There are certain idiomatic expressions where it's quite common, though, as in "I'm available Monday Tuesday Wednesday."

Comment: It also seems to happen quite often with *then*: "I walked to the park, then to the store, then back home again." Hmm.

Comment: This is information I never knew and I don't doubt it's accuracy.  I up-voted the reply.  But there is just something about the phrasing of the post that I don't understand.  The 2nd full paragraph mentions, "Sometimes when we have three or more coordinates, we can leave out the coordinator altogether."  But the 3rd full paragraph adds "It is also, possible to use asyndetic coordination with only two coordinates..."  Why include the "three or more" limit in the 2nd paragraph, only to contradict that in the 3rd?

Comment: @SyntaxJunkie I originally wrote, "sometimes, **usually** when there are three or more ..." but it read very awkwardly, so I edited that part out, and then it became confusing! Thanks for pointing it out. I've had another edit. Is that better?

Comment: @Araucaria-Notthereanymore. I appreciate the revision.  My own comment wasn't as clear as I would have liked it to be. I did get the impression from your answer that asyndetic coordination *usually* requires 3 coordinates, but *under certain conditions* only 2 can be used.  I wish I had asked more explicitly: What are those certain conditions?

Comment: @SyntaxJunkie They certainly seem to be more frequent with gapped coordination. However, aside from that I'm afraid I haven't done enough research to tell you *when* exactly asyndetic coordination with only 2 coordinates is more likely, I'm afraid. Certainly, it seems to me that it's fairly common in informal speech, as noted by Alphabet (their examples seem very realistic examples of normal, informal English speech to me). Aside from that I'm afraid I don't know! Sorry

Comment: @alphabet   You will never hear this in *spoken* English.   In some kinds of fiction and poetry, it is done intentionally, by authors who know the rules and at least believe that they are breaking them for a reason.

Comment: @alphabet When you see 'then', it is not a "comma splice".   "Then" functions just like "and" would - as a connecting word.   You need some connecting word between independent clauses.   Other connecting words are "but", "though", "if ", "or", "unless", "yet", and many others....

Comment: @BadZen Really? I'm pretty sure things like "I woke up, had breakfast, ran some errands" are fairly common in informal speech.

Answer (score 2):

Do not make sentences like these.   The connective "and" is required in each of these uses.

"The fat hand descended onto the globe, **and** stopped the spinning."

"Jessica turned away **and** looked out the window at the gathering darkness."

Authors will sometimes intentionally break grammar rules "creatively", for stylistic reasons.   This may or may not actually work for them in their writing, but as an English learner you should know that these sentences are ungrammatical.

We would not speak like this, and it is completely inappropriate to write these sentences in a formal or professional context.

Comment: I'll disagree with your first objection. Omitting the expected "and" breaks up the flow of the sentence, and emphasizes the deliberate nature of the action, and does so in a very economical way.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast All that may be true in terms of style, but it's still ungrammatical. On Writing.SE I'd agree with you, but not here.

Comment: @gotube Why do you say it is ungrammatical? Are you saying that  Dune is written in an ungrammatical way? I am surprised. Can you find a vetted grammar resource to back that up?

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. I say it's ungrammatical because generally in English, lists of conjugated verbs must be joined with a conjunction to make compound verbs. There are specific exceptions, I'm sure, but I don't see one here. So I'm saying Herbert took very well-calculated liberties. I don't have access to any authorities on Grammar like CGEL or Swan, but I'd like to see a source that explains what the exception here is

Comment: @gotube I very literally (in the original sense of the word) do not understand what you mean by "*lists of conjugated verbs must be joined with a conjunction to make compound verbs*". Could you explain, for a slow person like me, please? For instance could you illustrate with an example of conjugated verbs joined by a conjunction to make a compound verb, please? Thanks

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. I'll speak specifically to this context. I mean "descended" is a conjugated verb, and so is "stopped". To join these together to form a single verb phrase, you need to use a conjunction, like "and" or "or".

Comment: I disagree with your second claim. In informal speech this sort of construction is, I think, fairly common. "What did you do this morning?" "I woke up, had breakfast, ran some errands."

Comment: @gotube Ah, I see. We normally say that there is a coordination of two verb phrases rather than a single verb phrase.  So where does the compound verb come in? Or did you mean 'compound verb phrase'?

Comment: "Are you saying that Dune is written in an ungrammatical way? I am surprised."  Try reading it then, haha.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast "Omitting the expected "and" breaks up the flow of the sentence, and emphasizes the deliberate nature of the action, and does so in a very economical way."   It's also called a "comma splice" and is one of the most common errors that English language learners make.   You will lose points on an ESL or high school English exam if you do this.   You will also sound unprofessional in a formal context and perhaps even confusing.  Read more about comma splice:  https://www.grammarly.com/blog/comma-splice/ - this is one of the classic, "everybody-knows-better" grammar mistakes.

Comment: (You may perhaps agree with their opinion that "...in poetry, of course, the rules are even more relaxed.... sometimes a comma splice creates just the right rhythm." But you cannot say that it is proper grammar, you would be wrong if you said it was natures *spoken* English of any dialect, and you should *certainly not confuse English learners* by arguing it is an ordinarily acceptable use.)

Comment: @BadZen Strictly speaking, this isn't a comma splice; the conjuncts are verb phrases, not independent clauses.

Comment: That's a fair distinction, however the situation doesn't materially change if we add an "it" before "stopped" to make it a "proper" comma splice.